# Add a structure to a collection in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Recently I found that I'm not able to instantiate a structure for an array:

```
Dim mObjectLists() As New objectLayout
```

OK, fair, but it's an easy way to store a bunch of data in an array instead of defining a class. And after that, I tried to define this:

```
Dim mObjectLists() As Collection
```

And add structures to the collection. But it says you should instantiate the reference object first. I searched about creating my own **Collection** based on the base collection class, but I think it's wasting ones time to write code with class inheritance instead of the first sample.

What should I do to solve my problem like the first sample :).

Comment: Both arrays and generic collections should be able to contain structs. But you sound pretty confused. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: Dim mObjectLists() As objectLayout = New objectLayout(5){}

Comment: I said, I tried to store a structure in my array but it says you should instantiate it first and for the arrays the New keyword or instantiation is not allowed. Just like this. Egor4eg I tried it thanks. But if I don't put the maximum field for it, compiler gives me the error like the previous one I want to know how can I do it without defining the maximum field.

Comment: @MahanGM: You can't. In .NET you specify the size of the array when you create it. If you want a dynamic collection, you should use a `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim list As IList(Of NewStructure)
        list = New List(Of NewStructure)
        list.Add(New NewStructure() With {.Name = "test1"})
        list.Add(New NewStructure() With {.Name = "test2"})
        Console.WriteLine(list(0).Name)
        Console.WriteLine(list(1).Name)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Structure NewStructure
        Property Name As String
    End Structure
End Module
```